# Javaで最大公約数を求める

Tags: java

以下のようにgcd(a,b)を作って最大公約数を求めようと思ったのですが、繰り返しが終わらずに、公約数を求めることができませんでした。
どこが間違っているのでしょうか。

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b){

    while(true){
        System.out.println(a+" "+b);
        if(b==0)return a;
        gcd(b, a%b);
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args){

    int a,b;

    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    a=scan.nextInt();
    b=scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println(gcd(a,b));

    scan.close();
```

Comment: 参考：[ユークリッドの互除法](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E4%BA%92%E9%99%A4%E6%B3%95)。なお、アルゴリズムの勉強が目的でなければ、`BigInteger#gcd()`メソッドを使うのがもっとも高速に動作します。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gcd(b, a%b);`は`return gcd(b, a%b);`ではありませんか? あと`while`ループはいらないのでは．

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b){
    System.out.println(a+" "+b);
    if(b==0) return a;
    return gcd(b, a%b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

メソッドの再帰呼び出しについて理解が足りてないように感じたので勉強しましょう。
やりたい処理はこんな感じだと思います。

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {

   // 引き数のint値を表示
   System.out.println(a + " " + b);

    // bがゼロならaを返却
    if(b == 0) {
      return a;
    }

    // そうじゃないなら再計算
    return gcd(b, a%b);
}
```